# Firebase observeEventType completion block not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 FIRDatabaseReference *databaseRef = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

 [[databaseRef child:@"Groups"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
     NSLog(@"test");
 }];
```

Completion block is not called. Child with name "Groups" is there in Firebase website.

[image]

Comment: enable logging by  `FIRDatabase.setLoggingEnabled(true)` and check the result in logs

Comment: @Shubhank : After enabling logs , it shows "Permission denied". How to fix can you please help.

Comment: I got the solution ! In Rules need to pass read = "true". Anyways Thanks

Comment: A [tutorial](http://shubhank101.github.io/iOSAndroidChaosOverFlow/2016/05/todo-app-with-firebase-part-1-(Xcode)) that kinda explains it. Its also explained in the docs - read about security rules and authentication